# pthread and accessing the critical section

Tags: linux, operating-system, pthreads

Well, the below code is for two threads. I have some problem with the mutex.
After thread t1 is created, it calls add_queue(). Then it will signal the thread t2 to work in its critical section. But, the program does not run for thread t2.
Thread t1's runs and does its work in its critical section. Then, I have locked the mutex for thread t2. But, the program gets stuck in the line 29.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int pending_requests =0;
static pthread_mutex_t prmutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t prcondition = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

static int critical = 0;

int get_number_requests(void)
{
    return pending_requests;
}

void add_queue()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&prmutex);
    pending_requests++;
    critical++;    
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&prmutex);
    printf("xxxx\n");
    printf("critical=%d\n",critical);

}

void remove_from_queue()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&prmutex);
    pending_requests--;
    printf("BBBBcritical=%d\n",critical);
    critical--;
    printf("BBBcritical=%d\n",critical);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&prmutex);

}

void *get_request()
{
    add_queue();
    if (get_number_requests() != 0)
    {    
        printf("I have a element in the queue. Signalling to processor thread..\n");
        pthread_cond_signal(&prcondition);
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}

void *processor()
{
    while(get_number_requests() == 0)
    {
        printf("BBB This is a processor thread, I am waiting..\n");
        pthread_cond_wait(&prcondition,&prmutex);
    }
    while(get_number_requests() !=0)
    {
        printf("aaaa\n");
        remove_from_queue();
        pthread_cond_signal(&prcondition);
    }

    pthread_exit(0);
}


int main()
{
    pthread_t t1,t2;
    printf("critical=%d\n",critical);
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,get_request,NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,processor,NULL);
    printf("critical=%d\n",critical);

    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
    pthread_join(t2,NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `pthread_cond_wait` is wrong in a number of ways. Careful reading of the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait) for `pthread_cond_wait` will help you understand how to use it properly.

1. Before calling `pthread_cond_wait` the mutex must be locked. From the manual:

   > They shall be called with mutex locked by the calling thread or
   >   undefined behavior results.

   That is, you need to call `pthread_mutex_lock` before calling `pthread_cond_wait`.
2. When `pthread_cond_wait` returns it will have the mutex locked. From the manual:

   > Upon successful return, the mutex shall have been locked and shall be owned by the calling thread.

   So it is wrong to attempt to lock it again in `remove_from_queue`. Since the mutex is already locked, the `pthread_mutex_lock` call in `remove_from_queue` will block indefinitely as you are finding (ie, the thread has deadlocked itself).

Comment: Thanks, i will see that.